# MAX and MIN value of primary key

Tags: mysql, performance, where-clause

I have a query like this for finding the max/min values of primary key, which satisfy the where condition.

```
SELECT id 
FROM mytable 
WHERE date_created >= '2015-01-27 00:00:00' 
  AND date_created <= '2015-01-27 23:59:59' 
LIMIT 1
```

and EXPLAIN

```
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 44726469 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

and for maximum,

```
SELECT id 
FROM mytable 
WHERE date_created >= '2015-01-27 00:00:00' 
  AND date_created <= '2015-01-27 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

and EXPLAIN will give

```
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

As I am running this queries against a very large table, the query is getting time out. Is there any alternative method for finding these values?

id is the primary key and I already created index for date_created. But doesn't have any effect on the performance.

Comment: "As I am running this queires against a very large table, the query is getting timedout" --- mysql does not timeout queries - it runs them regardless how terrible they are.

Comment: Now objectives: 1. you missed `ORDER BY` in the first query 2. You didn't provide `EXPLAIN` and the actual `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: You are selecting with TWO columns in your `where` clause - `date_created` and `created_at`. So you should at least make a single index which covers BOTH these columns, not just `date_created`. This may not solve your problem entirely, but should be a step towards better performance.

And since you're only needing to get `id`, you could even make an index with three columns (`date_created`, `created_at`, and `id`) so the query can use only index to get the values, without any need to even read the data file.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what if it's innodb?

Comment: @TomasMatejicek for a range comparison the `created_at, id` part of the suggested index will **never** be used. So effectively your index is no different from a single column `date_created`

Comment: @zerkms you're right. However I'm unsure about the situation where id is selected with an aggregate function like MIN() or MAX(), as like SELECT MIN(id) FROM mytable WHERE date_created >= '2015-01-27 00:00:00' AND created_at <= '2015-01-27 23:59:59'

Comment: It's too late to use index for `MIN` as soon as `WHERE` contains predicates that don't use index

Comment: I tried with MIN(id), MAX(id) and it is also taking lot of time. I am getting the error Lost connection to mysql server and I think this is timeout.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because in innodb the clustered primary key is implicitly added to every key. So whenever you create an index for `created_at` column - it in fact is created as `(created_at, id)` implicitly. If you create such manually, then `id` will be added twice.

Comment: I have added EXPLAIN results.

Comment: And `CREATE TABLE`? **AN IMPORTANT NOTE**: all the queries and the `CREATE TABLE` must be **ORIGINAL, NOT MODIFIED IN ANY WAY** (yep, I see you're modifying it already, could you please not do that?)

Comment: @zerkms while mysql does not timeout queries before 5.7 a query could fail because of lock acquisition timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

creating  a trigger after insertion and deletion is a possible solution and maintaining a two row table for storing max,min value for primary key.

Comment: Trying to optimize such a trivial (see fast) operation following your advice in 99% of cases is a non-win way

Answer (score -1):

can you try this 
    SELECT MIN(id),MAX(id) FROM mytable WHERE date_created >= '2015-01-27 00:00:00' AND created_at <= '2015-01-27 23:59:59